# How to use a single save in spring data jpa with existing IDs

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have implemented a Spring Boot application using Spring Data JPA (and REST) and need to support the entity creation based on uploaded or on-server configuration files. I have created a service with the trigger method annotated using

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

The method is supposed to create a number of entities structurally similar to the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PARENT")
public class Parent {
  @Id
  @Column(...)
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "customUUID")
  UUID id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT")
  @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
  Collection<Child> children;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_CHILD")
@IdClass(...)
public class Child {

  @Id
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH })
  Parent parent;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private String name;
}
```

There is only a repository for the `Parent` (not for the `Child` entities). The ID values must be imported so a custom generator is used; this solves a problem similar to the one documented in [@Id @GeneratedValue but set own ID value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108178/id-generatedvalue-but-set-own-id-value).

This allows saving the parent entity first, then setting a list of children with the parent set to the just created parent (the object returned by `parentRepository.save(...)`) and then saving the parent entity again. The `@Cascade` annotation is needed in this scenario as one would otherwise run into the issue documented in [Spring data jpa detached entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037503/spring-data-jpa-detached-entity).

If the parent is not saved first, it will cause a `PersistentObjectException` with "detached entity passed to persist". If IDs are left to be `null`, a single save works.

While this works, it feels like too much work in the service layer. Surely this is something the ORM framework should be able to handle. I am also somewhat concerned that adding the two `@Cascade` annotations may interfere with how Spring Data (JPA/REST) works though I have not run into any problems during testing -  yet.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a better way to save an entity including all its related entities in a single save when IDs are set using a custom generator?
2. Is it reasonable to expect that the annotations do not cause problems with the Spring Data implementation?

PS: I know I could get the EntityManager autowired and save using that but I would lose (or maintain consistent duplicate implementations of) the per-method Spring Security checks attached to the various repositories using `@PreAuthorize` and similar annotations.