# How to save relationship of (detached) objects in java spring boot (jpa-hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, save, relationship, persist

I want to save a relationship of two or more persons to each other with specific elements. A person with its skill and on a specific address should be connected to each other. Normaly I creat a table to save the ID's of each element and create a row in the table (in normal MySQL with PHP).
How do I solve this problem in Java Spring Boot (JPA-Hibernate-MySQL)?

When I create (or better ask for) an "object" (detached) from the repository of each element and want to save it in a new "repository" (database) then I got an error.

PartnerConnectionServiceImplementation (.java)

```
@Service
public class PartnerConnectionServiceImpl implements PartnerConnectionService {

    @Autowired
    private PartnerConnectionRepository partnerConnectionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DanceSkillServiceImpl danceSkillDatabaseService;

    @Autowired
    private AddressLocationServiceImpl addressLocationDatabaseService;

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileServiceImpl userProfileDatabaseService;

@Override
    public Optional<PartnerConnection> connectPartnersWithDanceSkillAndAddressLocation(long userIdPartner1, long danceSkillIdPartner1, long addressLocationIdPartner1, long userIdPartner2, long danceSkillIdPartner2, long addressLocationIdPartner2) {

        Optional<UserProfile> userProfile1 = this.userProfileDatabaseService.getUserById(userIdPartner1);
        Optional<UserProfile> userProfile2 = this.userProfileDatabaseService.getUserById(userIdPartner2);

        Optional<DanceSkill> danceSkill1 = this.danceSkillDatabaseService.getDanceSkillById(danceSkillIdPartner1);
        Optional<DanceSkill> danceSkill2 = this.danceSkillDatabaseService.getDanceSkillById(danceSkillIdPartner2);

        Optional<AddressLocation> addressLocation1 = this.addressLocationDatabaseService.getAddressLocationById(addressLocationIdPartner1);
        Optional<AddressLocation> addressLocation2 = this.addressLocationDatabaseService.getAddressLocationById(addressLocationIdPartner2);

        if (
        (userProfile1.isPresent()) && (userProfile2.isPresent())
        ){
            Optional<PartnerConnection> theConnection = getPartnerConnectionOfPartners(
                    userProfile1.get(),
                    userProfile2.get());

            if (theConnection.isPresent()) {
                return theConnection;
            }
        }


        if (
                (userProfile1.isPresent()) && (userProfile2.isPresent()) &&
                (danceSkill1.isPresent()) && (danceSkill2.isPresent()) &&
                (addressLocation1.isPresent()) && (addressLocation2.isPresent())
        ) {
            PartnerConnection newPartnerConnection = new PartnerConnection(
                null,
                userProfile1.get(),
                danceSkill1.get(),
                addressLocation1.get(),
                userProfile2.get(),
                danceSkill2.get(),
                addressLocation2.get()
        );

        this.partnerConnectionRepository.save(newPartnerConnection);


        return Optional.of(newPartnerConnection);
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
...
```

PartnerConnection (.java)

```
// indicates the connecitons between partners/ users
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "partner_connection")
public class PartnerConnection {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;


    @OneToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "firstmessage_fk",    // foreign key
            nullable = true
    )
    private UserMessage firstMessage;

    @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "onepartner_fk",     // foreign key
            nullable = false)
    private UserProfile firstPartner;

    @OneToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "firstpartnerdanceskill_fk",    // foreign key
            nullable = false
    )
    private DanceSkill firstPartnerDanceSkill;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "firstpartneraddresslocation_fk",    // foreign key
            nullable = false)
    private AddressLocation firstPartnerAddressLocation;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "secondpartner_fk",   // foreign key
            nullable = false)
    private UserProfile secondPartner;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "secondpartnerdanceskill_fk",    // foreign key
            nullable = false)
    private DanceSkill secondPartnerDanceSkill;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "secondpartneraddresslocation_fk",    // foreign key
            nullable = false)
    private AddressLocation secondPartnerAddressLocation;


    public PartnerConnection(UserMessage firstMessage, UserProfile firstPartner, DanceSkill firstPartnerDanceSkill, AddressLocation firstPartnerAddressLocation, UserProfile secondPartner, DanceSkill secondPartnerDanceSkill, AddressLocation secondPartnerAddressLocation) {
        this.firstMessage = firstMessage;
        this.firstPartner = firstPartner;
        this.firstPartnerDanceSkill = firstPartnerDanceSkill;
        this.firstPartnerAddressLocation = firstPartnerAddressLocation;
        this.secondPartner = secondPartner;
        this.secondPartnerDanceSkill = secondPartnerDanceSkill;
        this.secondPartnerAddressLocation = secondPartnerAddressLocation;
    }
}
```

The error `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: ... nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: ...`  appears on `this.partnerConnectionRepository.save(newPartnerConnection);`

Do you have any easy to understand suggestions?

Comment: I think this question can help you: [Spring data jpa detached entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037503/spring-data-jpa-detached-entity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your method should contain @Transactional annotation. You have marked all relationships as LAZY, so if you want to get them You need a transaction to load them into managed state from detached one then be able to attach it to the object you want to save